# Sorting a python list by frequency of their absolute difference

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, sorting, frequency

I have a list like,

```
lst=[[3,7],[4,9],[8,3],[1,5],[9,4],[4,5],[3,0],[2,7],[1,9]]
```

And then want to sort this list by the frequency of their absolute difference like below:

```
|3-7|=4,  |4-9|=5,    |8-3|=5,    |1-5|=4,    |9-4|=5,    |4-5|=1,    |3-0|=3,    |2-7|=5,    |1-9|=8,
```

Out put should be:

```
[[4,9],[8,3],[9,4],[2,7],[3,7],[1,5],[4,5],[3,0],[1,9]]
```

I am doing:

```
list.sort(key=self.SortByDifference,reverse=True)

def SortByDifference(self, element):
    return abs(element[0]-element[1])
```

But, this return highest difference first.

I would like to sort by the frequency of the absolute difference, so instead of sorting by the highest difference, i.e. `[5, 5, 4, 4, 4, 3, 2, 1]`, it would output `[4, 4, 4, 5, 5, 3, 2, 1]` because `4` appears more often.

Comment: Removing `reverse=True` could help.

Comment: @wuerfelfreak No he doesn't want to sort by the number, he wants to sort by the frequency of the number.

Comment: Yes you are right. Overread that. Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try creating a new list called `newl`, then sort the `lst` list by how many times the `abs`olute difference appears in the `newl`:

```
lst=[[3,7],[4,9],[8,3],[1,5],[9,4],[4,5],[3,0],[2,7],[1,9]]
newl = [abs(x - y) for x, y in lst]
print(sorted(lst, key=lambda x: -newl.count(abs(x[0] - x[1]))))
```

Output:

```
[[4, 9], [8, 3], [9, 4], [2, 7], [3, 7], [1, 5], [4, 5], [3, 0], [1, 9]]
```

Comment: @Mohiuddin No problem, please accept and upvote if it works :-)

Comment: Could u explain the print statement so that I can extend my code? I am trying to split the list into sub-list based upon the same values(absolute difference)

Comment: @Mohiuddin Okay so inside the print statement I do a `sorted` function, which sorts the `lst` list, and I have a `key` argument. Which what's being declared to it is how it's gonna sort the list, it sorts by how many times the absolute difference of the two numbers in the list appear in `newl`.